# Apache poi to excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache  poi to export the values to excel.after reaching 32767 rows the values are stop printing.
I have implemented the logic for printing the valuesin other sheet,it works but values getting repeated....
Any solution??????

```
protected void populateRows(History history, String mmddyy, HSSFSheet ss) 
    {
        log.debug("populateRows(History, String,  HSSFSheet)");

        ArrayList<Unit> list = history.entryList;

        Iterator it = list.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) 
        {
            Unit u = (Unit) it.next();
            HSSFRow row = ss.createRow((short) ss.getLastRowNum() + 1);

//          HSSFRow row = ss.createRow(ss.getLastRowNum() + 1);//added by magesh

//          System.out.println("number of rows "+ ss.getLastRowNum());
            row = ExcelHelper.fillTheRowOnly(wb, row, numColumns);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

            if (u.id != 0)
            {
                row.getCell((short) COLNUM_ID).setCellValue(u.id);
            }

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_LENAME).setCellValue(history.lename);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_CORPTAXCODE).setCellValue(history.corptaxcode);

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_ADJUSTED).setCellValue(u.adjusted);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_ADJUSTED).setCellStyle(setPosFormat());

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_CARRYFORWARD).setCellValue(u.carryForward);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_CARRYFORWARD).setCellStyle(setPosFormat());

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_CUM_CARRYFORWARD).setCellValue(u.cumulativeCarryForward);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_CUM_CARRYFORWARD).setCellStyle(setPosFormat());

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_EXPIRED_SYSTEM).setCellValue(u.expiredSystemGenerated);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_EXPIRED_SYSTEM).setCellStyle(setPosFormat());

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_GENERATED).setCellValue(u.generated);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_GENERATED).setCellStyle(setPosFormat());

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_UTILIZED_SYSTEM).setCellValue(u.utilizedSystemGenerated);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_UTILIZED_SYSTEM).setCellStyle(setPosFormat());

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_UTILIZED).setCellValue(u.utilized);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_UTILIZED).setCellStyle(setPosFormat());

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_JURISDICTION).setCellValue(history.jurisdictionName);

            if (history.year != null)
            {
                row.getCell((short) COLNUM_NOLYEAR).setCellValue(formatter.format(history.year));
            }

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_NOTES).setCellValue(u.notes);

            if (u.unitType.equals(StateTaxConstants.NOL_ADJUSTMENT))
            {
                row.getCell((short) COLNUM_ADJUSTMENT_DESCR).setCellValue(u.adjusted_descr);
            }

            if(u.postDate != null)
            {
                row.getCell((short) COLNUM_POSTDATE).setCellValue(formatter.format(u.postDate));
            }

            if (u.referenceDate != null)
            {
                row.getCell((short) COLNUM_REFDATE).setCellValue(formatter.format(u.referenceDate));
            }

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_USERNAME).setCellValue(u.userName);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_FEIN).setCellValue(history.fein);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_REVIEWED).setCellValue(u.reviewed);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_PREPOST).setCellValue(u.prepost);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_HISTNAME).setCellValue(u.histname);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_YRENDORIG).setCellValue(u.yrendorig);

        }
    }
protected void populateRows(History history, String mmddyy, HSSFSheet ss) 
    {
        log.debug("populateRows(History, String,  HSSFSheet)");

        ArrayList<Unit> list = history.entryList;

        Iterator it = list.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) 
        {
            Unit u = (Unit) it.next();
            HSSFRow row = ss.createRow((short) ss.getLastRowNum() + 1);

//          HSSFRow row = ss.createRow(ss.getLastRowNum() + 1);         
//          System.out.println("number of rows "+ ss.getLastRowNum());
            row = ExcelHelper.fillTheRowOnly(wb, row, numColumns);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

            if (u.id != 0)
            {
                row.getCell((short) COLNUM_ID).setCellValue(u.id);
            }

            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_LENAME).setCellValue(history.lename);
            row.getCell((short) COLNUM_CORPTAXCODE).setCellValue(history.corptaxcode);          
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the `HSSF` prfixed object is the old 'xsl' style which can not have more the 32767 rows. Try the `XSSF` prefixed objects for new xlsx style

Comment: Here's the row limit for [Excel](http://superuser.com/a/366473/230998)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your code:

```
HSSFRow row = ss.createRow((short) ss.getLastRowNum() + 1);
```

you're casting the row index to short.

Try this code instead:

```
HSSFRow row = ss.createRow((int) ss.getLastRowNum() + 1);
```